# Tiny Core Linux persistent home directory

Tags: boot, home, persistence, tinycore

I have a command line **frugal** install of Tiny Core and I want to have a **persistent home directory**, because the programs I run save results there.

I read the [persistent option details](http://tinycorelinux.net/concepts.html) and followed [these instructions](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:persistent_home).
Already added the `home=UUID="xxxxxx"` boot option to the `/mnt/sda1/tce/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf` file and saved it with `filetool.sh -b`.

During the boot process the `home=UUID` part is printed to the console, the `extlinux.conf` file stays persistent, but when I create files in the home directory, they disappear after reboot.

Is there any way to make this work? If the system stops accidentally, will these permanent files remain there with the latest content, or the system saves them only on shutdown?

I also thought about creating a cronjob and execute backup script in every n minutes, but this is the last solution I would like to have.

Comment: *system saves them only on shutdown* - this, backup is done by shutdown script which uses tar to create mydata.tgz archive. You may do that archive on regular basis during TC work via cron by runnig that script, or tar which replaces mydata.tgz (first create second archive then rename them)

Comment: I tried it again, and added home=/dev/sda1 bootcode option during the the installation process, and the home directory is persistent now.

Comment: What type of system are you storing the files on?

Answer (score 1):

I followed this Tiny Core install guide, and I have a persistent home directory: http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:install_hd

The key is to install in Frugal mode, and in boot options add the partition where you installed after the next parameters for `Boot options`:

```
opt=sda1 home=sda1 tce=sda1
```